# Speed up Python script running ArcPy

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, performance, cx-oracle

I am using a script and would like to use as much ArcPy (ArcGIS Desktop 10.8.1 / ArcMap, not ArcGIS Pro) as possible to stick to the standard. Yet I do see a problem within the first step of my script.
I `import arcpy` and open up a connection to the database using

```
arcpy.ArcSDESQLExecute(sde_filename)
```

This takes about 600s on my machine. Yet the same connection with a cx_Oracle connection takes 1s max. I figured out, that ArcPy is reading the full system registry (>1'000'000 entries) prior calling the db which takes that long.

Is there a way how I can increase the speed of my ArcPy call?

Comment: Well, the only one I can think of is: Don't create a million tables in one database. It'd be nice if you didn't have to pay that price at connect, but you're going to have to pay it at *some* point, no later that the first `ListFeatureClasses` or `ListTables`..  If you don't need to process every table against every other table, you might want to look at creating multiple "silo" databases with tables that are used together.

Comment: @Vince, I see similar time just by writing this line arcpy.env.scratchWorkspace = r'c:\work\scratchoutput.gdb' #regEnumKey without using any DB-Connection at all, so it is not a DB-issue!

Comment: I've had to work with clients having ten thousand tables, and the "list all tables" call was unpleasant. Having two orders of magnitude more is inconceivable, both on need and database function. Since most users can access their C drive without a ten minute delay, there is obviously something fundamentally wrong with your install (and/or OS). Tech Support might have additional insight, but I doubt we can help.

Comment: The mentioning of "full registry (>1'000'000 entries)" is not regardimg the table but the system registry!

Comment: @Riccardo, if you mean the Windows Registry on the local PC when you say "the system registry," what tool are you using to determine that ArcPy is supposedly reading the full system registry?

Comment: I was checking it with procmon.exe

Comment: @Riccardo, I am not sure what is happening on your machine.  When I start a stand-alone Python session from an ArcGIS Pro 2.9.2 Python Command Prompt and import ArcPy followed by `arcpy.ArcSDESQLExecute(sde_filename)`, the Python process only touches 374 different registry paths.  If > 1 million registry paths are being touched when you do it, I think something is corrupt with your installation.

Comment: arcgis pro is also not of a problem here. it is good old arcmap. @bixb0012

Comment: @Riccardo, right, my bad.  You did state ArcGIS Desktop and not Pro in question.  I have access to ArcGIS Desktop 10.8.2 and will test.

Comment: @Riccardo, I finally got a chance to test ArcMap 10.8.2.  The Python process with ArcMap definitely touches more registry paths (810 total) than with ArcGIS Pro (374 total), but that is still significantly less than you are seeing.